# Create sliding effect by offsetting button position with image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a slider view which consists of 2 images, a chevron pointer and a slider line. My ultimate goal is to offset the button in the opposite direction to the chevron image so that when the user clicks the empty space the button will slide to its location. Below is a gif of me attempting to achieve this. My approach is quite manual and I suspect there is a sophisticated way of achieving my goal. I have it working when I click the button once, I suspect that on the other side I have my numbers wrong so it doesn't work when the image is on the left side of the screen.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

extension Animation {
    static func smooth() -> Animation {
        Animation.spring()
            .speed(0.7)
    }
}

struct SliderView: View {
    
    //this works as a toggle you can implement other booleans with this
    @State var partyType: Bool = false
    @State private var isOn = false
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0
    @State var height: CGFloat = 0
    let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Toggle("",isOn: $isOn).toggleStyle(SliderToggle())
        }
    }
        
    func imageWidthX(name: String) -> CGFloat {
        let image = UIImage(named: name)!
        let width = image.size.width
        
        return width * 2.5
    }
    
    func hostParty() -> Bool {
        
        if partyType {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct SlideEffect: GeometryEffect {
    var offset: CGSize
    
    var animatableData: CGSize.AnimatableData {
        get { CGSize.AnimatableData(offset.width, offset.height) }
        set { offset = CGSize(width: newValue.first, height: newValue.second) }
    }
    public func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        return ProjectionTransform(
            CGAffineTransform(
                translationX: offset.width,
                y: offset.height
            )
        )
    }
}

struct SliderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SliderView()
    }
}

struct SliderToggle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            VStack (alignment: .leading,spacing: 0){
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation() {
                        configuration.isOn.toggle()
                    }
                    
                }) {
                    Image("chevronPointer")
                        .clipped()
                        .animation(.smooth())
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                        .offset(x: geo.size.width - 100, y: 0)
                }
                .modifier(
                    SlideEffect(
                        offset: CGSize(
                            width: configuration.isOn ? -geo.size.width + imageWidthX(name: "chevronPointer") : 0,
                            height: 0.0
                        )
                    )
                )
                
                Image("sliderLine")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 40)
    }
}

func imageWidthX(name: String) -> CGFloat {
    let image = UIImage(named: name)!
    let width = image.size.width
    return width * 2.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worded the question pretty poorly but ultimately the goal I wanted to achieve was to have 2 buttons on a stack that controlled the view under it. When the opposite side is clicked the slider icon will travel to that side and vice versa. The offset made things a lot more complicated than necessary so I removed this code and basically created invisible buttons. IF there is a more elegant way top achieve this I would be truly greatful

```
 HStack {
                ZStack {
                        Button (" ") {
                                
                    withAnimation(){
                    configuration.isOn.toggle()
                    }}
                            .padding(.trailing).frame(width: 70, height: 25)
                        
                        
                    
    
                
               Image("chevronPointer")
                   
                   .clipped()

                   .animation(.smooth())
                   .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                //.offset(x: geo.size.width - 100, y: 0)


                   
               
                    .modifier(SlideEffect(offset: CGSize(width: configuration.isOn ? geo.size.width - imageWidthX(name: "chevronPointer"): 0, height: 0.0)))

                }
                Spacer()
                Button(" "){
                    withAnimation(){
                    configuration.isOn.toggle()
                    }
                }.padding(.trailing).frame(width: 70, height: 25)
            }
```